# ld linker ignores LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: fedora, compiling, intel, ld

I'm having trouble linking the Intel MKL libraries to use in building Julia with MKL support. I've had this problem with other projects as well, but here I'll focus on Julia. I have MKL installed in `/opt/intel`. I've tried:

- Running `/opt/intel/bin/compilervars.sh intel64`
- Running `/opt/intel/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh intel64`
- Adding the library (libmkl_rt.so) to LD_LIBRARY_PATH: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64_lin`
- Adding a file called "mkl.conf" within `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` with the contents `/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2019/linux/mkl/lib/intel64_lin`

After the last two I ran `sudo ldconfig`, but there hasn't been any change. How can I get Make to recognize this library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and files in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` configure the runtime linker, not the linker used during builds.

To build Julia with MKL, [you should](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/doc/build/build.md#intel-mkl)

- add

  ```
  USE_INTEL_MKL = 1
  ```

  to `Make.user`
- run

  ```
  source /opt/intel/bin/compilervars.sh intel64
  ```
- and build Julia from the same shell (so that the variables set by `compilervars` are taken into account).

Comment: Thank you, it was the `source` part that I was missing. Once I ran `source /opt/intel/bin/compilervars.sh intel64` rather than just `/opt/intel/bin/compilervars.sh intel64` I was able to compile successfully.